# Move the button to right side of screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I try move the button in the right side of screen, like the above icon,  I tried the
p-grid p-align-end vertical-container,  p-align-end  but i didn't succees it. Any help ?
[image]

```
 <div class="p-grid p-align-center">
          <div class="p-col-12">
              <button pButton type="button"  class="p-button-primary" label="{{changeQuantity}}">
              </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has the [`.float-right`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/#responsive) class that can be added to any item.

See the example I have attached:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<div class="p-grid p-align-center">
  <div class="p-col-12">
    <button pButton type="button"  class="p-button-primary float-right" label="{{changeQuantity}}">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```